# How to look into a range and set a value in a cell if there's a coincidence

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a function to set some contents on a cell of a spreadsheet from a data set by user through a prompt.

There are some parts working well and some problems

To put in context, we have a spreadsheet with a "calendar" as follows: every cell in the A:A range is a day of the school year, starting from September/1 in A1, September/2 in A2, and so. In the B column we have for now the holidays, vacation period and other. There are many "stable" days in a school year, such as Christmas day: every year is the same day and month (only changes year). Besides this, there are some days every school (almost in Spain) choose to get a little break.

First, we set function, input range (A column to compare) and output range (B columne, where we want to write new content). (the var *year* is given as an argument of the function, but is set here for testing)

```
function setSpecialHolidays() {
  var year = 2017;
```

I had to make a *parseInt* for this data, because when given as an argument detects it as a string and doesn't work well. But now is ok.

```
  var yearNumber = parseInt(year);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Calendar"+year);
  var inputRange = sheet.getRange('A1:A'+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var outputRange = sheet.getRange('B1:B'+sheet.getLastRow());
```

Here start a loop where we can input different days. Every day I set in the prompt the script has to set it in a cell corresponding the *date* and the content of the A column

I set this *ButtonSet* before the loop because I need it to start the while, as it will be still working until the user clicks "No" button.

```
  var specialHoliday = ui.alert('Click «Yes» to set a special holidays', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO); 
  while (specialHoliday == ui.Button.YES) {
    var dayPointer = ui.prompt('Please enter the special holiday date (DD/MM)');
    var specialHolidayDate = dayPointer.getResponseText();
    var specialHolidayDateParts = specialHolidayDate.split("/");
    var date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(specialHolidayDateParts[1] - 1, specialHolidayDateParts[0]);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

As the school year comprend two different natural years, to make possible *Date* compare, we need to ensure that if the month is from September to December is the *current year*, but if the month is from January to July or so is the *current year + 1", this is, the next year. Because of that I make this conditional. This is working well too. I've made some tests and *ui.alert* to be ensured and detects well the year, if current or next.

```
    if (specialHolidayDateParts[1] <= 8) {
      date.setYear(yearNumber + 1);
    } else if (specialHolidayDateParts[1] > 8) {
      date.setYear(yearNumber);
    }
```

Here is were doesn't work. Once we have set correctly the input date we can start compare it with all values in the *inputRange*. Then, look every A column cell and, *when* find a coincidence set in the *outputRange* the string.

I think there's probably a better solution to this problem, maybe doesn't making a loop, but this is a proccess I've followed  before in other functions of this script and that's well for now. This specific date setting is the last step of our program (for now), but I'm

```
    for (var i = 0; i < inputRange.length; i++) {
      var dateCompare = new Date(inputRange[i][0]);
      if (dateCompare == date) {
        outputRange[i][0].setValue("Holiday: special holiday");
      }
    }
```

Finally, if user wants to set another day, *ButtonSet* allows it. When users finish click "NO" instead of yes and everything stops. That's working too.

```
    var specialHoliday = ui.alert('Do you want to set a new special holiday?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  }
```

Well, thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What about it exactly doesn't work? It sounds to me like it works it's just inefficient, are you just trying to optimize it?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach, is not working where the script have to set the output data. I think there's a problem with the array, but I don't know how to ensure it.

Comment: You are comparing date objects as the test to set the value.  If you want the date/time to match exactly, even to the millisecond, then you should compare the the number of milliseconds of both dates.  If you just want to match the day of the year, then you should get the year and day of each date and compare them.  If you want an exact match, then you should probably use `now()` on both date objects and then compare the milliseconds to milliseconds.

Comment: @SandyGood, I've ensured the _Date_ objects are the same, event to the milisecond. By placing setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) on the input date, I have the same values. I've seen it through different _ui.alert_ messages. Then, the compare and evaluation is ok, the trouble is in putting in place the result, in the `for` loop. I dont know if is a trouble with writing, with arrays or other think I've not in mind. Thanks for comment and help!

Comment: You should answer your own question.  Otherwise, this question will be displayed as being unanswered.  For anyone who has the same issue, when they are searching posts, they will probably look for posts with answers.  Please consider how your posts can help others in the future.

Comment: @SandyGood sorry, I wanted to do it, but I don't know how to do, I was reading some docs to do it but I've finally decided to write as an edit, excuse me :( for next tries... which is the proccess to auto-answer a question after it has been posted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I've made some tries and finally I've found the correct way to do what I want, to set a value in a cell next to a cell that have a date I've compared from a user input date. There was a mistake in the statement:

- In a range I can't *setValues* (but I was trying...)
- Is needed to use the *.getTime()* method on compare the date values

Here is the (I think!) corrected code for the `for` loop:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < inputRange.length; i++) {
      var dateCompare = new Date(inputRange[i][0]);
      if (dateCompare.getTime() == date.getTime()) {
        outputRange[i][0] = "Holiday: special holiday";
      }
    }
```

I finally understood the problem in *outputRange*: as a range, I can't *setValues*, because is not a cell, then, I've to assign the value as is. What I'm not sure to get is why I need the *.getTime()* after every compared value. But it works!